# Understanding Theorem 17.2 in Munkres

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation

[image]

Essentially the only problem I'm having with this whole proof is the assertion that $A = Y \cap C \implies Y - A = Y \cap (X - C)$, I just can't seem to see how the implication holds true. I tried to derive it from elementary set theory operations but failed.

Any hint on how to prove this assertion, that $A = Y \cap C \implies Y - A = Y \cap (X - C)$?

Comment: First step: use the assumption, and rewrite $Y-A$ to $Y-(Y\cap C)$. Second step: show set equality the way you usually do (inclusion both ways).

Comment: A Venn diagram will help clarify.

Comment: Which direction are you stuck on, $Y-A\subseteq Y\cap(X-C)$ or $Y\cap(X-C)\subseteq Y-A$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$Y\setminus A = Y\setminus(Y \cap C) =Y \cap (Y \cap C)^C = $$$$=Y \cap (Y^C \cup C^C) = (Y \cap Y^C) \cup (Y \cap C^C) = Y \cap C^C = Y \cap (X \setminus C)$$

This is it without double inclusion, using only elementary set theory operations

Answer (score 4):

Proving the two inclusions is the most elementary way, I think:

Let $x \in (X -C) \cap Y$. So $x \in Y$ and $x \notin C$. As $A = C \cap Y$, this means that $x \notin A$ either, so $x \in Y - A$.

On the other hand, if $x \in Y - A$, $x \in Y$ and $x \notin A = C \cap Y$. This means that $x \notin C$ (otherwise $x \in A = C \cap Y$), so $x \in X - C$, hence $x \in (X-C) \cap Y$.